# How do I time an ajax query (send query, processing, receive response)

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

**Edited to clarify my intent:** (based on initial answers)

I have a web app. The server consists of a set of Java POJOs and I'm using Jersey to expose these as REST APIs. The browser calls these APIs, using jquery ajax, and does stuff.

I want to log the duration that my ajax queries take, and I want a break down by

1. How long it took to send the query from browser to server (into my Java POJO)
2. How long it took for the Java POJO to process the request
3. How long it took for response to be transmitted to browser (from POJO exit point to onComplete: entry point in javascript)

I'm also looking for a code based solution that I can apply systematically across my app.

So, 2 on its own is trivial, and timing the whole sequence is trivial. But I'm not sure about getting the breakdown for 1 & 3. I was initially going to pass the system time as a GET param, and compare to currentTimeMillis on the server - but this relies on the browser system time being in sync with the server system time. Unlikely to be reliable.

Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: To answer this question you really need a good overall picture of network traffic, server processing (E.G. IIS Load analysis - logs), and possibly some timers in client/server side code.  I think the timers are trivial to implement.  It's the rest of the stuff that requires a complex analysis of server logs and network tools.  Therefore, this question should be closed as non-constructive.  As it stands it is too vague.

Comment: Why do you want to know 1 and 3? It is not something you can do much about anyway. And it should be the same across al requests. What you can do something about, and monitor, is the size of request and response. But that is another question.

Comment: @Mikael - This app will be consumed by mobile as well as desktop machines. So, I'm sensitive to network times. If 3 is large on a 2G/3G network then I'll need to rethink how the client interacts with the server.

Comment: @Kevin then you need to test it once with some different sizes of requests. and determin what sizes are ok and what sizes arent?

Comment: @Mikael Yes, it is useful to know what the acceptable sizes are. It is also very very useful to continuously measure during development what the actual sizes are. Hence the desire to constantly measure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[How do you determine exactly when, accounting for network latency, a HTTP request was sent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271031/how-do-you-determine-exactly-when-accounting-for-network-latency-a-http-reques)", the answer explains how you can "calibrate" the client-side time with the server-side time. Note that this calibration ***will not be exact***. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can't. Certainly not from within a browser using Ajax.

The server could put the processing time in a custom response header, the client knows the send/receive times, from this it easy to derive the round trip time and assumes symmetrical link performance.
Going beyond that effectively means you want to measure TCP performance.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for a couple of pages and a couple of calls i would suggest using Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools. It provides plenty of info.

Comment: It is something I want to systematically add across my app, so I'm looking for a code based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you are looking for...

```
function myAjax(){

  var timer = {};
  timer["start"] = new Date().getTime();

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else{
    var req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }     

  req.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(req.readyState===2){
      timer['recieved'] = new Date().getTime() - timer['start'];
    }
    if(req.readyState===3 && !timer['processing']){
      timer['processing'] = new Date().getTime();
    }
    if(req.readyState===4 && req.status===200){ 
      timer['processing'] = new Date().getTime() - timer['processing'];
      timer['full'] = new Date().getTime() - timer['start'];
      console.log(timer);
    }
  } 

  req.open("get", "myScript.php", true);
  req.send();
}
```

Times are held in the timer variable. This obviously is not exact and may not even be what you are looking for, but is a simplified version of some AJAX times.